# Creating an NPM module that works on both vue and express side

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

So, I'm creating an Auth module for my backend that works with both nodejs/express & vue. I've got the node/express side down but im having trouble also using vue within the module. Maybe I'm just not doing it right? I'm not really sure how to even do it at the moment. Here is my app.js:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const db = require('./db/index');
const jwt = require('./jwt')

/**
 * @user User object passed from register form. Requires a username/password
 * @return True / False based on if user was registered or not 
 */
exports.register = function(user) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
    .then((hash) => {
      user.password = hash;
      db.createUser(user).then((res) => {
        res ? resolve(res) : reject('Error Occured')
      }).catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
    })
    .catch((err)=> {console.log(err)})
  })
}

/**
 * @username Username from form
 * @password Password from form
 * @return JWT Token applied to username or null
 */
exports.login = function(username, password) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    db.getUserByName(username).then((user) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res) {
        if(res) {
          delete user.password
          jwt.assignToken(user).then((token) => {
            resolve(token)
          }).catch((err)=> { reject(err) })
        } else {
          reject(err)
        }
      });    
    }).catch((err)=>{ reject(err) })    
  })
}
```

and this would be my vue.js within the same folder

```js
const app = require('./app')

exports.install = function (Vue, options){
  Vue.prototype.$login = function(){
    app.login()
  }
  Vue.prototype.$register = function(){
    app.register()
  }
}
```

Obviously its just basic as i havn't started any work on it yet but it would use functions from app.js. Whats the most efficient way to incorporate this so I can use one module for both my vue/nuxt frontend and my express backend?

Comment: What problems specifically? Also client and server side authentication must necessarily have different implementations.

Comment: @AluanHaddad being able to use the module as both a vue plugin and an express module

Comment: That's still not specific. _How_ is it not working?

Comment: I think you might be going about this all the wrong way. You shouldn't be having your Vue app that runs on the client side connecting to the database. The frontend should request to an endpoint that will log in.

Comment: This is my first npm module so I'm still trying to figure things out. What I'm really looking to know is how to get vue to use the vue aspect of my module and express to use the other